# Android - How to make last item of gridview to be different?

Tags: android, gridview

I am using gridview with custom adapter. Each item in Grid contains an imageview and checkbox but I want last item to be a button.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return thumbUrls.size()+1;
    }
```

I returned +1 in getcount to make getview called one extra time.

In getview: -

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(row==null)
        {
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.griditem, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mainImage = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.itemgrid);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.itemselected);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        if (position==(thumbUrls.size()+1)) { //this is just to show what i am trying to do.
        Button button = new Button(context);
        return button;
        }
        else
        {
            setImageSize(holder.mainImage);

            holder.mainImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    intent.putExtra("position", position);
                    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("MainUrls", mainUrls);
                    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("Thumbnails", thumbUrls);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
            holder.checkBox.setTag(position);

            holder.checkBox.setChecked(positions.contains(thumbUrls.get(position)));
            holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.mainImage, thumbUrls.get(position), R.drawable.extras_load);
        }
        return row;

    }
```

Comment: if you return a button, you won't have a ViewHolder in the tag in the next getView that recyle this view, and you'll crash when accessing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
    if (position==(thumbUrls.size()+1)) { //this is just to show what i am trying to do.
    Button button = new Button(context);
    return button;
    }
```

use

```
    if (position == thumbUrls.size()) { 
    Button button = new Button(context);
    return button;
    }
```

The first parameter `position` in `getView` starts at 0. You should also set an appropriate `LayoutParameter` for the `Button`.

Comment: what a stupid error i made. Thanks Rajesh. Really appreciate it.

Comment: i am having a strange issue. Everything is working fine but button sometime showing up and sometime it doesn't. Why is it so? I have put it as a new question. Take a look : - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888169/android-different-items-in-gridview-not-showing-up